# select multiple columns from subquery

Tags: mysql

```
SET @query = 'select SUBQUERY.ABC,SUBQUERY.DEF from (SELECT abc as \'ABC\' ,def as \'DEF\',ghi as \'GHI\' from table) as subquery group by ABC order by DEF';
```

I want to select particular columns from my subquery using a stored procedure. But when am trying this am getting exception as "unknown column "SUBQUERY.ABC" in field list". I tried this also

```
select ABC,DEF from (SELECT abc as \'ABC\' ,def as \'DEF\',ghi as \'GHI\' from table) as subquery group by ABC order by DEF';
```

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: use sa;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test()
   BEGIN
  SET @query = 'select SUBQUERY.ABC,SUBQUERY.DEF from (SELECT abc as \'ABC\' ,def as \'DEF\',ghi as \'GHI\' from table) as subquery group by ABC order by DEF';

   PREPARE stmt_query FROM @query;
     -- SELECT @query;
                EXECUTE stmt_query;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_query;
   END //

 DELIMITER ;

Comment: What you have posted works fine for me. Are you having an issue trying to use this stored procedure in another query?

Comment: i am getting this exception "unknown column "SUBQUERY.ABC"